# execute KNIME workflow using python or java in LINUX system

Tags: java, python, knime

I have a workflow based on logistic Regression created on KNIME Analytics Platform. Now I want to run that project as a backend with the help of java or python in a LINUX machine. Is it possible? if yes please tell me how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [KNIME FAQ](https://www.knime.com/faq#q12) states you can execute your workflow from the command line on a Linux machine:

To run the workflow "Knime_project":

```
knime -nosplash -application org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION -workflowDir="workspace/Knime_project"
```

You can also change the configuration of the workflow:

```
 -workflow.variable=my_integer,5,int
```